# Problem with ALSA with Raspberry Pi 4b and voice recognition

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi4, alsa

I get the following error:

```
def recognizer():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as voice:
            listen = sr.Recognizer()
            voices = listen.listen(voice, 2, 30)
            command = listen.recognize_google(voices, language="es-ES")
    except:
        command = ''
    return command

print(recognizer())
```

I get the following error, and it does not return the speech_recognition information:

```
Expression 'GetExactSampleRate( hwParams, &defaultSr )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 895
Expression 'GetExactSampleRate( hwParams, &defaultSr )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 895
Expression 'GetExactSampleRate( hwParams, &defaultSr )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 895
Expression 'GetExactSampleRate( hwParams, &defaultSr )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 895
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1075:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
Expression 'GetExactSampleRate( hwParams, &defaultSr )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 895
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.USB-Audio.pcm.hdmi.0:CARD=1,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5233:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM hdmi
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.USB-Audio.pcm.hdmi.0:CARD=1,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5233:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pulse.c:242:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

ALSA lib pulse.c:242:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

ALSA lib pcm_a52.c:823:(_snd_pcm_a52_open) a52 is only for playback
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1075:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1075:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Expression 'GetExactSampleRate( hwParams, &defaultSr )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 895
Expression 'GetExactSampleRate( hwParams, &defaultSr )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 895
Expression 'GetExactSampleRate( hwParams, &defaultSr )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 895
Expression 'GetExactSampleRate( hwParams, &defaultSr )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 895
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1075:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
Expression 'GetExactSampleRate( hwParams, &defaultSr )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 895
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.USB-Audio.pcm.hdmi.0:CARD=1,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5233:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM hdmi
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.USB-Audio.pcm.hdmi.0:CARD=1,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5233:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pulse.c:242:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

ALSA lib pulse.c:242:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

ALSA lib pcm_a52.c:823:(_snd_pcm_a52_open) a52 is only for playback
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1075:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1075:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
```

In the PulseAudio control it detects the microphone correctly and also if I record a recording the microphone can be heard perfectly. So I think it is something related to the Python permissions and the sound card, although I run it with the superuser and the same error happens.

I'm using Raspberry Pi OS, running Python 3.9.2 with the speech_recognition library and when I ran this code:

```
def recognizer():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as voice:
            listen = sr.Recognizer()
            voices = listen.listen(voice, 2, 30)
            command = listen.recognize_google(voices, language="es-ES")
    except:
        command = ''
    return command

print(recognizer())
```

Comment: This question may yield more help over at [Raspberry PI](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange where folks can speak to both the programming and the physical set up to help troubleshoot further.

Answer (score 0):

I find a similar error. We have something in common and that is that we are using the Spanish language and speech recognition with the Speech_recognition library. The Raspberry Pi 4 peripherals also worked well for me. For a moment I thought it could be the 3.5 jack microphone I'm using, but seeing your problem I'm leaning toward it being a conflict with Speech_recognition.